# SQL Server stored procedure meaning

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm developing a simple database architecture in VisualParadigm and lately ran over next code excerpt.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'getType') AND type in (N'P', N'PC')) 
DROP PROCEDURE getType;
```

Next goes my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getType @typeId int
AS
SELECT * FROM type t WHERE t.type_id = @typeId;
```

Can anyone explain what does it mean/do (the former one)?

P.S.: It would be great, if you may also check for any syntax errors as I'm totally new to SQL Server and stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IF EXISTS part first checks if a stored procedure with the same name exists. if it does it drops it before creating it. Without this check you'd get an error that the stored procedure already exists.

Comment: Sorry, but that's obvious. What about the inner select part? What is this sys.objects?

Comment: Sorry, this IS obvious. Sys.objects is a system table containing ALL OBJECTS. I kindly refer you to your trusty SQL Server documentation (try it), also available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx - explains sys.objects.

Comment: How do I accept comment as a correct answer (instead of only up vote it)? :)

Answer (score 1):

a `CREATE PROCEDURE getType...` will fail if the object already exists.  by including the `IF EXISTS...` code which will drop the object if it exists first, you eliminate the error and the `CREATE...` will run.

The `OBJECT_ID(N'getType')` just returns the numeric ID of an object named N'getType' and the `AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))` makes sure that the  object is a P=stored procedure or a PC=Assembly (CLR).

You could try using something like this, so you can use `ALTER` to keep permissions (DROP+CREATE removes any):

```
BEGIN TRY EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedureName AS SELECT ''ERROR'' RETURN 999') END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE YourProcedureName 
AS
SELECT 'WORKS!2'
GO

EXEC YourProcedureName
```

OUTPUT:

```
-------
WORKS!2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Raj's post, there is no means to do an "upsert" with stored procedures. The Create Procedure statement must be the first statement of the batch. Thus, the following would **not** work:

```
If Not Exists(Select 1 From sys.procedures Where Name = 'getType')
    Create Procedure...
Else
    Alter Procedure...
```

The only means to "update" a procedure and not have it throw an error if it already exists is to drop it and re-create it.

**ADDITION**

To address a specific question you made in comments, sys.objects is a catalog view which contains a list of all objects (tables, constraints, columns, indexes etc. Every "thing" in the database) of which procedures are one of them. Thus, this is checking whether the procedure object (based on filters on type) exist. The primary key of the sys.objects table/view is object_id which is an integer. In your example, they are using the `OBJECT_ID` function to find the id of the object `getType` and determine if it is a procedure. (It probably would have been safe to just use `If OBJECT_ID(N'getType') is not null` but just in case there is another object with that name that isn't a procedure, they added the check on the object type).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is part of a script to generate your DB.  The first statement looks to see if your sproc called "getType" exists.  If it does then it will drop it.  Why?  Because the next line is going to create it.

The only other way it could create it and make sure it matches the current version  of your procedure is to change `create` to `alter`.  That would make for longer code because it would have to list the sproc twice.  Or it could generate dynamic sql which is not nearly as clean.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing a **drop and recreate**

if a database object called getType exists:

```
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'getType')
```

and it's a stored procedure:

```
AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
```

then drop it before adding your stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE getType;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query drops procedure if it exists. The second creates a new procedure that takes integer parameter and returns resultset.